# Printing even characters in a string and ignoring white strings

Tags: python

I need something like this
`accepted_string: An apple a day keeps the doctor away`
`resultant_string: Aapedyepteotrwy`

And for this I have written this code:

```
accepted_string = input("enter")
add = ''

for count in range(0, len(accepted_string), 2):

    if accepted_string[count] == " ":
        count += 1
        add = add + accepted_string[count]
    else:
        add = add + accepted_string[count]
print(add)
```

But this is giving me different output while passing the above sample input. The logic is also correct, then where is the error? I have to skip to next character whenever I encounter a whitespace. Please help me as I am new to this

Comment: If you want to increment the for-loop variable from inside the loop, do `continue`, don't do `count += 1`

Comment: Your code is giving different results because you only inspect every second character to see if it's a whitespace and skip it, so on average you miss half the whitespaces.

Comment: @smci yes i got it now, thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove space before hands instead of doing in for loop and make it list to convert in into array

**Code:**

```
accepted_string = input("enter")
add = ''
accepted_string = list(accepted_string.replace(" ", ""))
print(accepted_string)

for count in range(0, len(accepted_string), 2):
    add = add + accepted_string[count]

print(add)
```

**output:**

```
['A', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'y', 'k', 'e', 'e', 'p', 's', 't', 'h', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'w', 'a', 'y']
Aapedyepteotrwy
```

**2nd code:**

```
accepted_string = input("enter")
add = ''

char_count = 1
for count in range(0, len(accepted_string)):

    if accepted_string[count] != " ":
        char_count += 1
        if char_count % 2 == 0:
            add = add + accepted_string[count]
        # add = add + accepted_string[count]
    # else:
    #     add = add + accepted_string[count]
print(add)
```

**output:**

```
Aapedyepteotrwy
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But the constraint is that I can not use any in built function. Have to skip the space if it is on even index and move to next .

Comment: check now. without inbuilt function

Comment: your answer is correct but I couldn't understand the logic of using another char_count

Comment: i am counting the string length at the same time as taking only even indexed char

Answer (score 2):

Simple [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) with prior [replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> s = "An apple a day keeps the doctor away"
>>> s.replace(" ", "")[::2]
'Aapedyepteotrwy'
```

Comment: "Look mom, no loops!" +1 for the pythonic answer